# How do I wrte an XSLT template that excludes some elements but includes others?

Tags: xslt

How do I write an XSLT template that takes all non "meta" and "answer" elements and deposits them into a "my_question" template?  So, for example, given the below XML ...

```
<question>
    <meta>
        ...
    </meta>
    <para />
    <para>Why?</para>
    <answer weight="1" correctness="0">
        ...
    </answer>
    <answer weight="1" correctness="0">
        ...
    </answer>
    <answer weight="1" correctness="100">
        ...
    </answer>
    <answer weight="1" correctness="0">
        ...
    </answer>
</question>
```

I would want the result to be

```
<my_question>
    <para />
    <para>Why?</para>        
</my_question>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity template is your friend

```
<xsl:stylesheet
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 version="2.0">

 <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <my_question>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="question"/>
     </my_question>
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- ignores the specified elements. Adjust for nesting if necessary. -->
 <xsl:template match="meta | answer"/>

 <!-- Pass everything else -->
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

you start with a identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

run it, and you will see, that everything will be transformed.

Then, you selectively remove nodes, e.g. like this:

```
<xsl:template match="answer" />
```

Read this link for more information: http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity
It's very detailed. Good luck!